# Typescript: declaring and implementing a curried Method

Tags: typescript, currying

In the skeleton of the following class

```
class Iterable<A> {

    filter( filter: ( value: A ) => boolean ): Iterable<A> { ... }

    map<B>( f: ( value: A, index?: number ) => B ): Iterable<B> { ...}

    collect = <B>( filter: ( value: A ) => boolean ) => ( mapper: ( value: A ) => B ): Iterable<B> => { ... }

}
```

there is a curried property `collect` which is implemented this way

```
collect = <B>( filter: ( value: A ) => boolean ) => ( mapper: ( value: A ) => B ): Iterable<B> => {
    return this.filter( filter ).map( mapper )
}
```

This property is basically a curried function that takes two functions as argument and returns an `Iterable<B>`. With `this`, being an `Iterable<A>`, it can be used in the following manner:

```
const it: Iterable<string> = this.collect<string>( f => true )( ( v: A ) => v.toString() )
```

Now, I would like to transform this property into a class *method* but I am failing to find the right syntax

- declaring

  ```
  collect<B>( filter: ( value: A ) => boolean ): ( mapper: ( value: A ) => B ) => Iterable<B>
  ```

  will preserve its usage (see `it`above), however I do not know how to implement it as the method expects to return a `Function`, not an `Iterable`
- declaring

  ```
  collect<B>( filter: ( value: A ) => boolean ) => ( mapper: ( value: A ) => B ) : Iterable<B>
  ```

  is invalid...

---

Solution: (see @JLRishe and @NitzanTomer answers) I went for an explicit type declaration:

```
collect<B>(filter: (value: A) => boolean): (mapper: (value: A) => B) => Iterable<B> {
    return (mapper: (value: A) => B) => this.filter(filter).map(mapper);
}
```

Comment: Can you put the code for your class as well? For example what's this `A`, what does `this.filter` returns? etc..

Comment: @NitzanTomer `A` is a generic, see my edits above with the skeleton of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it like this:

```
collect<B>(filter: (value: A) => boolean) {
    return (mapper: (value: A) => B) => this.filter(filter).map(mapper);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
collect<B>(filter: (value: A) => boolean) {
    return (mapper: (value: A) => B): Iterable<B> => {
        return this.filter(filter).map(mapper);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Same solution as JLRishe... who has beaten you on the clock (according to SO)